# Remove Toolbar title margin in ActionMode

Tags: java, android, toolbar, android-actionmode

I'm looking to remove the space between the navigation icon and the title of my actionMode. I managed to remove it for the toolbar thanks to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/cusToolbarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="cusToolbarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar">
        <item name="titleMargin">0dp</item>
        <item name="contentInsetStartWithNavigation">0dp</item>
        <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

[image]

However I can not change the mode action to remove the space on the photo:
[image]

Comment: Check this out `toolbar.contentInsetStartWithNavigation = NUMBER` use this in your java/kotlin code.

Comment: It is rather toolbar.setContentInsetStartWithNavigation(0); no ? And it doesn't change anything when I put this in onCreate method

Comment: @CodingFR its the same thing, @abstractArrow's code is Kotlin. I think, you can use `LayoutInspector` in the latest version of Android Studio to find out the `id` of the `TextView` along with other attributes such as `margin_start`. If you know `id` then, you can create the `TextView` object and play with its attributes as you like. Try seeing if this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it was complex and difficult but I used LayoutInspector such as suggested to me @cgb_pandey. So I found the system identifier of the close ImageView and add the below code to the onPrepareActionMode method:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
       AppCompatImageView imageView = findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.action_mode_close_button);

       if (imageView != null) {
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
           params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
           imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
       }

       return false;
   }
```

Comment: So, is this working? In fact, I just noticed that I also have a significant gap in my `Toolbar` too xD

Comment: Yes it works perfectly even if it is not optimized;)